# API factory for a realtime chat site

Tags: javascript, angular.js

I was told I'm using factories wrong, but I'm not so sure. Any ideas? (I know I should be using GET; I've only just noticed that)

```
app.factory('apiFactory', ['$http', function($http){
    var apiFactory = {};

    apiFactory.initUser = function(){
        return  $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "api/new_user.php",
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
        });
    };

    apiFactory.hostOrClient = function(session){
        return $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "api/sessionhostclient.php",
            data: $.param({"session":session}),
            headers:{"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
        });
    };

    apiFactory.hasPlayerJoined = function(session){
        return $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "api/sessionstatus.php",
            data: $.param({"session":session}),
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
        });
    };

    apiFactory.sendMessage = function(session, message){
        return $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "api/addmessage.php",
            data: $.param({"message":message, "session":session}),
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
        });
    };

    apiFactory.checkMessages = function(session, id){
        return $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "api/getmessages.php",
            data: $.param({"session":session, "id":id}),
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
        });
    };

    apiFactory.getAllMessages = function(session) {
        if(session == null){
            return;
        }

        return $http({
            method:"POST",
            url:"api/getallmessages.php",
            data: $.param({"session":session}),
            headers:{"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
        });
    } ;

    apiFactory.getMessagesFrom = function(session, id){
        return $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "api/getmessages.php",
            data: $.param({"session":session, "id":id}),
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
        });
    };

    return apiFactory;
}]);
```

Comment: So, does it not work as intended?

Comment: Absolutely. The factory itself is working like clockwork. I was just told I should learn how to use a factory... I always thought they were used for exactly what Im doing here. Maybe so?

Answer (score 3):

James Heald said:

> I was told I'm using factories wrong, but I'm not so sure.

The people telling you that are technically correct. A "factory" is an object or method whose sole purpose for existence is to create other objects. Factories are generally used when you want to create a concrete sub type, but return either an interface or a common parent type.

From [Wikipedia: Factory (object-oriented programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28object-oriented_programming%29)

> In class-based programming, a factory is an abstraction of a constructor of a class, while in prototype-based programming a factory is an abstraction of a prototype object. A constructor is concrete in that it creates objects as instances of a single class, and by a specified process (class instantiation), while a factory can create objects by instantiating various classes, or by using other allocation schemes such as an object pool. A prototype object is concrete in that it is used to create objects by being cloned, while a factory can create objects by cloning various prototypes, or by other allocation schemes.

Your `apiFactory` object is *technically* returning "new" objects, but since it is making web service calls, you've actually created a "service object".

More info: [AngularJS Services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).

Really the problem is the name "apiFactory" because the `apiFactory` variable itself is not a factory. It is a service. A more appropriate name might be `ChatService`.

The function that returns `apiFactory` is actually the **factory**, whereas `apiFactory` is actually the **service**.